# How to use simple form for comments from a nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

So I'm creating a blog rails app and I'm trying to create a comment session on the blog. I'm trying to render a form using simple form, but I'm having a hard time getting the simple form to work. For now I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for ([@user, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :comment %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

but it says that post.comments isn't a defined path.

My comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

post belongs to user and has_many comments
user has many post and has many comments

Here are my current routes:

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments 
  end
```

Any advice?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix to this by generating a migration for the comment. I just had to make sure that everything with an association actually had the columns in the database. After that I just made sure I was rendering the @post.comment instead of comment/comment. Hope this helps anyone that came across the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you sending @user in simple_form_for?
Use `@post` in place of `@user`.

Comment: Will give it a try! The reason why I put @user is because I wanted a comment to belong to a user.

Answer (score 1):

remove user from the form.

```
<%= simple_form_for [@post, @post.comments.build] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :comment %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

and then you will assign the user value in the controller using something like `current_user` if you are using devise.

```
def create
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
   @comment.user = current_user
   @comment.save
   redirect_to @post
end

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)
end
```

it's a bad idea to have a model named `comment` and a field into it named `comment`. I would prefer to call it `content`

Comment: Thanks sooo much! Will give this a try now. I'm using Devise. Do I need to generate a migration file for users? to something like add_comments_to_users?

Comment: your comments table must have a user_id column and a belongs_to :user. You'll need to implement your comment_params method id the controller. I update the answer.

Comment: Thanks again! Been trying to figure this out for the last couple of hours, I keep getting the error message , "undefined method `comments' for #<Post:0x007fe25d28e280>", I came across a fix by generating a comment migration, but each time I try to submit a comment ,Missing template comments/create, application/create. I already have the def create method in the comment controller

Comment: you need a `post_id` column in comment and a `has_many :comments` on post model which `belongs_to :post`. for the other error I updated the answer. you need to redirect to a know page after creating the comment like the show page of the post